# Show modal bottom sheet with custom animation

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I was playing around with `showModalBottomSheet()` in Flutter and I was thinking about changing the default slide from bottom animation. Looking throught [flutter documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html) I saw that there is in fact a BottomSheet class that accept animation as parameters but, accordingly to the page, `showModalBottomSheet()` is preferrable.

Is possible to control the animation in some way? I just need to change the default curve and duration.

Thanks

Comment: go to the sources of `showModalBottomSheet()` method (ctrl-left click) and you will see that it simply uses `_ModalBottomSheetRoute` - so check how the `AnimationController` is creaed in that class

Comment: I saw the implementation and I can't understand how can I simply add a custom curve. Any clue?

Comment: @justAnotherOverflowUser did you got the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the AnimationController [drive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Animation/drive.html) method to modify the animation curve, and [duration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/duration.html) and [reverseDuration](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/AnimationController/reverseDuration.html) to set how long the animation will go on. These can be declared on your `initState()` if you're using a StatefulWidget.

```dart
late AnimationController controller;

@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  controller = BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this);
  
  // Animation duration for displaying the BottomSheet
  controller.duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  
  // Animation duration for retracting the BottomSheet
  controller.reverseDuration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  // Set animation curve duration for the BottomSheet
  controller.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn));
}
```

Then configure the BottomSheet `transtionAnimationController`

```dart
showModalBottomSheet(
  transitionAnimationController: controller,
  builder: (BuildContext context) {
    return ...
  }
)
```

Here's a sample that you can try out.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BottomSheetAnimation extends StatefulWidget {
  const BottomSheetAnimation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _BottomSheetAnimationState createState() => _BottomSheetAnimationState();
}

class _BottomSheetAnimationState extends State<BottomSheetAnimation>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController controller;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = BottomSheet.createAnimationController(this);
    // Animation duration for displaying the BottomSheet
    controller.duration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    // Animation duration for retracting the BottomSheet
    controller.reverseDuration = const Duration(seconds: 1);
    // Set animation curve duration for the BottomSheet
    controller.drive(CurveTween(curve: Curves.easeIn));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'BottomSheet',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('BottomSheet'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: TextButton(
            child: const Text("Show bottom sheet"),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet(
                context: context,
                transitionAnimationController: controller,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return const SizedBox(
                    height: 64,
                    child: Text('Your bottom sheet'),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo

[image: Demo]

Comment: controller.drive sets nothing, just converts input value and returns it, look at the source code